# SAS SCAN Function and Missing Values

Tags: sas, missing-data

I am trying to develop a recursive program to in missing string values using flat probabilities (for instance if a variable had three possible values and one observation was missing, the missing observation would have a 33% of being replace with any value).

Note: The purpose of this post is not to discuss the merit of imputation techniques.

```
DATA have;
    INPUT id gender $ b $ c $ x; 
    CARDS; 
    1 M Y . 5 
    2 F N . 4 
    3   N Tall 4 
    4 M   Short 2 
    5 F Y Tall 1
    ;

/* Counts number of categories i.e. 2 */
proc sql; 
    SELECT COUNT(Unique(gender)) into :rescats 
    FROM have 
    WHERE Gender ~= " " ;
    Quit;

%let rescats = &rescats; 
%put &rescats; /*internal check */

/* Collects response categories separated by commas i.e. F,M */
proc sql; 
    SELECT UNIQUE gender into :genders separated by ","
    FROM have
    WHERE Gender ~= " "
    GROUP BY Gender;
    QUIT;

%let genders = &genders;
%put &genders;  /*internal check */

/* Counts entries to be evaluated. In this case observations 1 - 5 */
/* Note CustomerKey is an ID variable */
proc sql; 
    SELECT COUNT (UNIQUE(customerKey)) into :ID
    FROM have
    WHERE customerkey < 6;
QUIT;

%let ID = &ID;
%put &ID; /*internal check */

data want; 
SET have;
DO i = 1 to &ID; /* Control works from 1 to 5 */
seed = 12345; 
/* Sets u to rand value between 0.00 and 1.00 */
u = RanUni(seed);  
/* Sets rand gender to either 1 and 2 */
RandGender = (ROUND(u*(&rescats - 1)) + 1)*1; 
/* PROBLEM Should if gender is missing set string value of M or F */
IF gender = ' ' THEN gender = SCAN(&genders, RandGender, ','); 
END;
RUN;
```

I the SCAN function does not create a F or M observation within gender.  It also appears to create a new M and F variable.  Additionally the DO Loop creates addition entry under within CustomerKey. Is there any way to get rid of these?

I would prefer to use loops and macros to solve this.  I'm not yet proficient with arrays.

Comment: You have a lot of different issues with this code. Which one is the main issue you are having?  What did you try to fix it?

Comment: "It also appears to create a new M and F variable."  You should solve this issue first.  Can you think why it would create a variable named M?

Comment: I know you said imputation method was out of scope, but why wouldn't you use one of the MI methods instead. For categorical, I like using a decision tree to predict the best value. You should also look at the RNDTBL() or Bernoulli random variable to directly get your 1 and 0. As others have mentioned, there's a lot wrong in your code so far.

Comment: Title is a little off as there is nothing recursive in this algorithm.

Comment: Post the expected output from your sample data as well.

Comment: My best guess i the syntax associated with the SCAN function is creating the F and  M variables. Specifically that gender = F and M (as governed by SCAN.  I don't believe that macro variable &genders with the values from PROC SQL would creates do this.  Would SCAN create these variables?

Comment: I have tried changing the input to the SCAN algorithm (i.e. genders), specifically from "M F" to "M,F". This result in no change to the output. I have changed the values assigned to gender via the program to RandGender. This successfully assigns the values 1 and 2 to gender within the data set. As such this was somewhat successful.

Comment: I am unclear on why my original code would generate the following variables: i, seed, u, and RandGender.  Having reviewed user667489's suggested code I believe that declaring working variables as u =, RandGender, etc has this effect.  Is this the case?  Is there a better way to declare working variables? Or should declaration of variables be avoided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my attempt at tidying this up a little:

```
/*Changed to delimited input so that values end up in the right columns*/
DATA have;
INPUT id gender $ b $ c $ x;
infile cards dlm=',';
CARDS; 
1,M,Y, ,5
2,F,N, ,4
3, ,N,Tall,4
4,M, ,Short,2
5,F,Y,Tall,1
;

/*Consolidated into 1 proc, addded noprint and removed unnecessary group by*/
proc sql noprint; 
    /* Counts number of categories i.e. 2 */
    SELECT COUNT(unique(gender)) into :rescats 
    FROM have 
    WHERE not(missing(Gender));
    /* Collects response categories separated by commas i.e. F,M */    
    SELECT unique gender into :genders separated by ","
    FROM have
    WHERE not(missing(Gender))
    ;   
Quit;
/*Removed redundant %let statements*/
%put rescats = &rescats; /*internal check */
%put genders = &genders;  /*internal check */

/*Removed ID list code as it wasn't making any difference to the imputation in this example*/

data want; 
SET have;
seed = 12345; 
/* Sets u to rand value between 0.00 and 1.00 */
u = RanUni(seed);  
/* Sets rand gender to either 1 or 2 */
RandGender = ROUND(u*(&rescats - 1)) + 1; 
IF missing(gender) THEN gender = SCAN("&genders", RandGender, ',');  /*Added quotes around &genders to prevent SAS interpreting M and F as variable names*/
RUN;
```

Comment: Thank you!  I am a novice when it comes to SAS programming.  A lot of my code was trying to iron out prior errors.  I won't run this today.  However, this looks like a viable set of solutions that will fix this program and expand my skill base.

Comment: There is no need to run the query twice to record how many records it found. Just save the SQLOBS automatic macro variable after pulling the data. `%let rescats=&sqlobs;`

Answer (score 1):

Halo8:

```
/*Changed to delimited input so that values end up in the right columns*/
DATA have;
INPUT id gender $ b $ c $ x;
infile cards dlm=',';
CARDS; 
1,M,Y, ,5
2,F,N, ,4
3, ,N,Tall,4
4,M, ,Short,2
5,F,Y,Tall,1
;
run;
```

- Tip: You can use a dot (.) to mean a missing value for a character variable during INPUT.
- Tip: DATALINES is the modern alternative to CARDS.
- Tip: Data values don't have to line up, but it helps humans.

Thus this works as well:

```
/*Changed to delimited input so that values end up in the right columns*/
DATA have;
INPUT id gender $ b $ c $ x;
DATALINES; 
1 M Y .     5
2 F N .     4
3 . N Tall  4
4 M . Short 2
5 F Y Tall  1
;
run;
```

- Tip: Your technique requires two passes over the data.

  - One to determine the distinct values.
  - A second to apply your imputation.
  - Most approaches require two passes per variable processed. A hash approach can do only two passes but requires more memory.

There are many ways to deteremine distinct values: SORTING+FIRST., Proc FREQ, DATA Step HASH, SQL, and more.

Tip: Solutions that move data to code back to data are sometimes needed, but can be troublesome. Often the cleanest way is to let data remain data.

**For example: INTO will be the wrong approach if the concatenated distinct values would require more than 64K**

Tip: Data to Code is especially troublesome for continuous values and other values that are not represented exactly the same when they become code.

**For example: high precision numeric values, strings with control-characters, strings with embedded quotes, etc...**

This is one approach using SQL.  As mentioned before, Proc SURVEYSELECT is far better for real applications.

```
Proc SQL;
  Create table REPLACEMENTS as select distinct gender from have where gender is NOT NULL;
  %let REPLACEMENT_COUNT = &SQLOBS;  %* Tip: Take advantage of automatic macro variable SQLOBS;

data REPLACEMENTS;
  set REPLACEMENTS;
  rownum+1; * rownum needed for RANUNI matching;
run;

Proc SQL;
  * Perform replacement of missing values;
  Update have
    set gender = 
      (
        select gender 
        from REPLACEMENTS
        where rownum =  ceil(&REPLACEMENT_COUNT * ranuni(1234))
      )
    where gender is NULL
  ;

%let SYSLAST = have;
DM 'viewtable have' viewtable;
```

You don't have to be concerned about columns not having a missing value because no replacement would occur in those.  For columns having a missing the list of candidate REPLACEMENTS excludes the missing and the REPLACEMENT_COUNT is correct for computing the uniform probability of replacement, 1/COUNT, coded as rownum = ceil (random)

Comment: Why would my current code, without the changes Richard and user667489 have suggested, create the variable "M" and "F"? Additionally my current code creates addition variables such as "i", "seed", "u", and "Rand Gender".  How can I avoid this in the future?

Comment: I ran all code of yours in this thread, and none of it create new variables M and F.  I suggest either find the specific variation that produces that output or just let it go as 'failed effort leading to learning'.  The speculation is that some code used the &gender macro variable in a non-quoted scope such as incorrectly attempting to arrayify the sql generate macro variable in statement such as [ array genders &gender; ]  Essentially, any data step construct that could compile M,F in an unquoted context would add those symbols to the PDV and become part of the output data set.

Comment: Just to be sure I understand you Richard:  &gender was not quoted (" "). As such SAS didn't know what to do the string values.  SAS changed the values into variables. It is your best guess that SAS resolved this issues by turning M & F into variables. Correct?

Comment: That is pretty close.  In this specific case the exact meaning of the term 'variables' changes from sentence to sentence.  SQL INTO moved data from a data set into a macro variable.  Macro at the core is simply a text processing environment.  Macro variables exist as scoped symbols within a running SAS session.  Data step variables exist as items in the program data vector that exist within a running Data step (runtime).  When a macro variable (aka symbol) resolution is specified in source code as &<symbol> the value of the symbol is placed in the source code stream.

Comment: Recommended reading "A SAS® Programmer's View of the of the SAS Supervisor" Ian Whitlock, Westat Inc.", SUGI 22 Proceedings, 1997 found at http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi22/ADVTUTOR/PAPER34.PDF.   The references at the end are also great reads for the serious SAS programmer.